# Address of the object - void* and void**

Tags: c++, memory, function-pointers, void-pointers, virtual-functions

I was trying to get vtable address which is stored in y but I don't understand why x contains a different address.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
    public:
        virtual int f() {
            return 2;
        }
};


int main() {
    A obj;
    void* x = (void**)&obj;
    void* y = *((void**)&obj);

    std :: cout << x << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << y << std :: endl;

    void** vtable = (void**)y;
    std :: cout << ((int(*)())(vtable[0]))() << std :: endl;

}
```

Comment: First: this is madness, especially the function call.  There’s mo guarantee that *any* function pointer type exists that’s compatible with a member function, virtual or otherwise.

Comment: `x` is the address of `obj`—the `(void**)` is irrelevant.  `y` is a “proper” type-pun (and is undefined behavior).

Comment: Why do you think that `(void**)&obj` and `*((void**)&obj)` would be the same address? Maybe I've misunderstood completely.

Comment: I don't understand why I have an address of vtable in Y after that type-pun.

Comment: Lots of UB here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all undefined behaviour, but the following code will give you that vtable address:

```
A obj;
void **vtable = * (void ***) &obj;
```

Making some assumptions about the layout of the vtable, we can demonstrate that this is so:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void f () { }
};


int main() {
    A obj;
    void **vtable = * (void ***) &obj;
    std :: cout << vtable << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << *vtable << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << (void *) &A::f << std :: endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0x400e88
0x400de4
0x400de4
```

Multiple and / or virtual inheritance would make this a lot harder to do.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/roku1gCxKqMlUegX)

Comment: Is that cast std?